# How do you join the database tables from your authentication and resource server?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oauth, asp.net-identity

Following the OAuth specification, I have two separate servers with databases, one for my webapplication (resources) and one for Asp.Net Identity (the authentication server). In my application, the resource server database contains a table users, that, for this example, looks like this:

```
Table: Users
  [Id]
  [UserName]
```

And my Identity table on the authentication server that looks like this:

```
Table: AspNetUsers
  [Id]
  [Email]
  [EmailConfirmed]
  [PasswordHash]
  [SecurityStamp]
  [PhoneNumber]
  [PhoneNumberConfirmed]
  [TwoFactorEnabled]
  [LockoutEndDateUtc]
  [LockoutEnabled]
  [AccessFailedCount]
  [UserName]
```

The username is always shared across the two databases. If your username is Timmy, both databases have a row with username Timmy. If you were to delete Timmy from the resource server, he should be removed from the authentication server as well. I can't find any information on how to solve this in code. How do I create a link between the username columns in my resource server and my authentication server? Do I:

- Add a context to the authentication server in my resource server? In that case, you lose the point of separating resource and authentication servers.
- Do I add the authentication tables to my resource database, or my resource tables to my authentication database? Either one of this will remove the separation of servers as well.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: I would go for the first option, and have a code layer to join them and abstract the two stores from your code.